# Copying from an InputStream to a BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I am sending a file over a socket and am trying to write it to a file at the receiver.

I've seen examples that do something like this:

```
int bytesRead = 0;
while (bytesRead != -1)
{
    bytesRead = networkInputStream.read(buffer, 0, diskBlockSizeEstimate);
    bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

However, from http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29 it souunds like .read returns -1 when the end of the stream is reached. Then when .write is called with -1, an exception is thrown. Do I have to implement logic that says "if(bytesRead==-1) set bytesToRead = fileSize - totalBytesRead" or something like this:

```
int fileSize = ... get filesize from sender ...;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
int bytesRead = 0;
while (bytesRead != -1)
{
    bytesRead = networkInputStream.read(buffer, 0, diskBlockSizeEstimate);
    if(bytesRead == -1)
    {
       bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, fileSize - totalBytesRead);
       totalBytesRead += fileSize - totalBytesRead;
    }
    else
    {
       bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }
}
```

Also, would it be better to do while(totalBytesRead != fileSize) instead of while(bytesRead != -1) ?

Comment: If you are copying blocks of memory, you don't need a buffered stream. Buffering is for turn small reads/writes in to larger reads/writes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My typical loop for this sort of thing looks like this:

```
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

While I don't *usually* like performing an assignment within a condition (loop or `if`) this is a sufficiently common pattern for this particular use case that you get used to it very quickly.

Note that the `read` here is just for the whole buffer - I'm not sure why you'd want to limit it to `diskBlockSizeEstimate`... or if you *do* want that as the largest amount to read each time, just create the buffer with that size to start with.

Comment: But won't that call .write(buffer, 0, -1) the last time through the loop? (which is illegal http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#write%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29). Or actually, I guess it will not call that write(..., -1) because the loop will not re-enter on that condition, but then it will never write the last bytes to the output?

Comment: @DavidDoria: No, it won't - because when the value assigned is -1, the loop will exit rather than go into the body.

Comment: Sorry I was too quick on the trigger. I edited the comment asking won't it just never write the bytes in the last read?

Comment: @DavidDoria: The last read which actually reads something will return the number of bytes read, rather than -1.

Comment: Ah, so when -1 is returned no bytes are actually read - I get you know. Thanks!